# Let $X$ be uncountable and $A$ be a countable subset of $X$. Then $X$ and $X \setminus A$ are equinumerous

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, infinity

> Let $X$ be uncountable and $A$ be a countable subset of $X$. Then $X$ and $X \setminus A$ are equinumerous.

---

I have previously proved that *Suppose that $X$ is infinite and that $A$ is a finite subset of $X$. Then $X$ and $X\setminus A$ are equinumerous* [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912030/suppose-x-is-infinite-and-a-is-a-finite-subset-of-x-then-x-and-x-setm). I have a feeling that the result can be extended by this theorem, so I tried to give a shot.

> Does this proof look fine or contain gaps? Do you have suggestions? Many thanks for your dedicated help!

---

**My attempt:**

*Lemma 1*: If $A \sim \Bbb N$ and $B \sim \Bbb N$, then $A\cup B \sim \Bbb N$.

*Lemma 2*: If $X$ is uncountable, then there exists $B\subsetneq X$ such that $B \sim \Bbb N$.

There are only two cases.

1. $A$ is finite (I presented a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912030/suppose-x-is-infinite-and-a-is-a-finite-subset-of-x-then-x-and-x-setm))
2. $A$ is infinite

Then $A$ is countably infinite and consequently $A\sim\Bbb N$.

Since $X$ is uncountable and $A$ is countable, then $X\setminus A$ is uncountable. By *Lemma 2*, there exists $B\subsetneq X\setminus A$ such that $B \sim \Bbb N$.

Let $f_1:(X\setminus A)\setminus B \to (X\setminus A)\setminus B$ be the identity map on $(X\setminus A)\setminus B$, then $f_1$ is a bijection.

Since $A\cup B\sim \Bbb N$ by *Lemma 1* and $A \sim \Bbb N$, there exists a bijection $f_2:B \to A\cup B$.

We define $f:X\setminus A \to X$ by $f(x)=f_1(x)$ for all $x\in (X\setminus A)\setminus B$ and $f(x)=f_2(x)$ for all $x\in B$. Thus $f$ is a bijection.

Hence $X\setminus A \sim X$.

Comment: Perfect. ${{{{{}}}}} $

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let $A$ be any uncountable set, and let $B$ be a countable subset of $A$. Prove that the cardinality of $A = A - B $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355049/let-a-be-any-uncountable-set-and-let-b-be-a-countable-subset-of-a-prove)

Comment: @PhysMath I have ask for proof verification, not for a solution, so I think it's not a duplicate :)

Comment: @LeAnhDung My bad, I have retracted the flag, but I'll keep the comment since the solution for that question is very similar to the one you have for yours. Its worth looking at I think