# Suppose $X$ is infinite and $A$ is a finite subset of $X$. Then $X$ and $X\setminus A$ are equinumerous

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, infinity

Although the title is the same as one in [Suppose $X$ is infinite and $A$ is a finite subset of $X$. Then $X$ and $X \setminus A$ are equinumerous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912030/suppose-x-is-infinite-and-a-is-a-finite-subset-of-x-then-x-and-x-setm), but the proof is different. Hence it's not a duplicate.

---

> Suppose $X$ is infinite and $A$ is a finite subset of $X$. Then $X$ and $X\setminus A$ are equinumerous

---

**My attempt:**

*Lemma 1*: If $A$ is finite and $B$ is countably infinite, then $A\cup B$ is countably infinite.

*Lemma 2*: If $X$ is infinite and $A$ is finite, then $X\setminus A$ is infinite.

*Lemma 3*: If $Y$ is infinite, then there exists $B\subsetneq Y$ such that $B$ is countably infinite. (Here we assume Axiom of Countable Choice)

---

Since $X$ is infinite and $A$ is finite, then $X\setminus A$ is infinite by *Lemma 2*.

Since $X\setminus A$ is infinite, there exists $B\subsetneq X\setminus A$ such that $B \sim \Bbb N$ by *Lemma 3*.

Since $A$ is finite and $B$ is countably infinite, then $A\cup B \sim \Bbb N$ by *Lemma 1*.

Since $B \sim \Bbb N$ and $A\cup B \sim \Bbb N$, $B \sim A\cup B$ and thus there exists an bijection $f_1:B \to A\cup B$.

Let $f_2:(X\setminus A)\setminus B \to (X\setminus A)\setminus B$ be the identity map on $(X\setminus A)\setminus B$. Then $f_2$ is a bijection.

We define $f:X\setminus A \to X$ by $f(x)=f_2(x)$ for all $x \in (X\setminus A)\setminus B$ and $f(x)=f_1(x)$ for all $x \in B$. Thus $f$ is a bijection.

Hence $X\setminus A \sim X$.

---

> Does this proof look fine or contain gaps? Do you have suggestions? Many thanks for your dedicated help!

Comment: What does X/A/B mean?

Comment: @WilliamElliot $X\setminus A\setminus B=(X\setminus A) \setminus B$.

Comment: @WilliamElliot it's *\setminus*

Comment: Perfect $\;\!$, just one note, the identity map of $Y$ is usually denoted by $\mbox{id}_Y$, in this case you have $f_2\equiv \mbox{id}_{(X\setminus A)\setminus B}$, but the name doesn't affect the proof

Comment: Thank you so $\infty$ @Holo! You have confirmed many of my recent attempts. Your help is really really helpful to me, removing my uncertainty. Since I'm self-studying without any teacher besides MSE, your help is extremely meaningful to me. By that noble conduct and your generosity, you have distinguished yourself from other users. I'm deeply grateful.

Comment: @LeAnhDung I'm happy I was useful$\ddot\smile$