# Cardinality and subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a proper infinite subset of some set $X$. If $x, y$ are two distinct
elements of $X$ that are not in $A$, we may set $B = \{x, y\} \cup A$. What is the
cardinality of $B$ in terms of the cardinality of $A$? Justify your answer.

It's probably wrong but if $B$ is the union of $\{x,y\}$ and $A$, then isn't the cardinality of $B$ just the cardinality of $A + 2$?

Comment: If $A$ is infinite, so is $B$.

Comment: $A$ is an infinite subset. Adding a finite number of elements to an infinite set leaves the cardinality unchanged. Do you see why?

Comment: Yes I do, I glazed over the fact that A is an infinite subset. Thanks!

Comment: real-analysis??

Comment: Consider $A=\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}=X$ and take $\{\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}\}$ as $\{x,y\}$.

Comment: Please consider using Mathjax!

Comment: $\operatorname{card}(B)=\operatorname{card}(A)+2$ is certainly correct; that would be my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

It's better for you to define the term *cardinality* of a set rigorously first.

More generally, we have:

> If $X$ is infinite and $Y$ is a finite subset of $X$, then $X$ and $X\setminus Y$ are equinumerous (or equivalently, have the same cardinality).

The gist of the above theorem lies in the fact that *If $X$ is infinite, then there exists $B\subseteq X$ such that B is countably infinite (Here we assume Axiom of Countable Choice)*.

Try to prove this theorem as an exercise.

For your reference: [Suppose $X$ is infinite and $A$ is a finite subset of $X$. Then $X$ and $X \setminus A$ are equinumerous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912030/suppose-x-is-infinite-and-a-is-a-finite-subset-of-x-then-x-and-x-setm)

and [Suppose $X$ is infinite and $A$ is a finite subset of $X$. Then $X$ and $X\setminus A$ are equinumerous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2915402/suppose-x-is-infinite-and-a-is-a-finite-subset-of-x-then-x-and-x-setmi)