# If $A$ is infinite, $B$ is finite and $B \subset A$ and $C=A\setminus B$. Is there bijection between A and C?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Here is my reasoning so far: $A$ is a infinite set and $B$ is a finite subset of $A$, therefore $B\subset A$.

If $C=A\setminus B$ that means that $C$ also is infinite and also, $C\subset A$.

Though, how could one prove that there is a bijection between $A$ and $C$?

Comment: For your reference, [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2915402/suppose-x-is-infinite-and-a-is-a-finite-subset-of-x-then-x-and-x-setmi?rq=1) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912030/suppose-x-is-infinite-and-a-is-a-finite-subset-of-x-then-x-and-x-setm).

Comment: @LeAnhDung Thanks, exactly what I needed.